# I cannot go to google.com and other websites due to invalid certificate; possible DNS issue?

Tags: windows-7, networking, dns, virus, malware

I am using Windows 7 on my PC's and my wife and I both have IPhones.

About a 2 weeks ago I was having a problem on the PC's where google.com would sometimes give a 404 not found and then in the middle of the screen say "ngix". I attempted to fix this by resetting the host file back to default (nothing in it but comments). This seemingly fixed the ngix problem, but then other weird things started happening.

I keep getting invalid certificates on web sites such as google.com, linkedin.com, godaddy.com and others. The kicker is now this problem is intermittently occurring on both my PC's, one virtual machine (on a PC) and also on both my IPhone and my wife's IPhone.

From what I have read this could be caused by a DNS problem that tries to take me to a bogus site instead of the real site. I have looked at the host files again on my PC's and they look fine (there is nothing in them, everything is commented out). I have also looked at the DNS settings on my router and I see nothing suspicious. I could easily be missing something though because I am not trained in networking or system administration.

I have scanned with several anti-virus and anti-malware tools, including malwarebytes, AVG, Norton and others, and none of them find anything. Virus definitions are up-to-date.

I finally got fed up with the invalid certificate on my phone when I go to google.com so I clicked to continue anyway and I was carried to a coupons.com website. I closed it immediately. I have no clue what is going on. I hate to have to wipe my computers as that might not even fix the issue if it is a DNS problem on the router.

I have powered off the router, waited 30 seconds, then powered it back on; that had no effect.

Any assistance with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE 3 (6/29/2014)

I reset the route to factory settings. So far I have saw no funny behavior so I am confident it is fixed! Thank you arielnmz, your advise was very helpful in troubleshooting this issue.

UPDATE 2 (6/28/2014):

Just got this when trying to go to https://www.reddit.com

"You attempted to reach www.reddit.com, but instead you actually reached a server identifying itself as a248.e.akamai.net. This may be caused by a misconfiguration on the server or by something more serious. An attacker on your network could be trying to get you to visit a fake (and potentially harmful) version of www.reddit.com."

UPDATE 1 (6/28/2014):

In Short: 
This problem still exists, but I just changed the DNS on my router and I am hoping that will resolve. Only time will tell though.

Details:

Per arielnmz suggestions:

- I installed adwcleaner and it was able to find several problems which I cleaned. Problem persists.
- I used msconfig.exe to look for suspicious startup apps or services. I did find a Coupon Printer Service that I did not trust so I uninstalled it using add/remove programs. Supposedly it is a legit app (my wife says so ;) but I don't trust it.
- I disabled browser extensions (I did not have many).
- I reset my host file.
- I still see this problem on other machines; even our phones.
- I am getting a lot of invalid certificate problems when I go to reddit.com or explicitly go to https://www.google.com
- Just now got an error on my iphone when it booted that said "cannot verify the identity of calendar.google.com do you want to continue anyway?". I click no. This is even after changing my DNS servers to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 :(
- I changed the DNS on my router by performing the following. On Basic Setup page in the DHCP Server Setting section, I entered 8.8.8.8 as Static DNS 1 and I entered 8.8.4.4 as Static DNS 2. I then rebooted and I suddenly can go to reddit.com without getting a invalid certificate. That was promising, but then I rebooted my iphone and that is when I got the calendar.google.com error message mentioned above.

I'll give this a couple days to see if problem persists. I will update either way and go from there.

Thanks for the help!

---

Comment: What do you mean you updated the HOSTS file? What did you put in it? What all is in it? What brand of router do you have in your house? Is resetting your router to the default configuration an option?

Comment: Doing a wipe won't solve this issue...

Comment: Ok, so you've changed the DNS for dhcp, did you try changing your router's default DNS too?  They're different and it may work too. Also, try forcing your computers and cellphones to retrieve new dhcp information, it may just be that they haven't retrieved the correct information yet. Also what is the address and DNS information displayed on your systems?

Comment: I will google how to change router's default DNS and how to force new dhcp info.

Comment: Since the error messages you are receiving are telling you there's a problem with the website certificates, does it not seem obvious to look at the certificates to try and find out what the problem is? Certificates have nothing to do with DNS.

Comment: never crossed my mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, scan your computer with anti-malware software. I'm aware you've already tried with some apps, I suggest you also run a check with [adwcleaner](http://www.infospyware.com/antispyware/adwcleaner/), it's a freeware and portable alternative. Here are some useful steps to solve this kind of issue:

1. Use antimalware and antivirus software (✓).

   - Check that no suspicious or unwanted software is lodaded at startup: <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and execute `msconfig.exe`, uncheck all apps that run at startup. Many apps aren't identified as actual *malware*, hence why your antimalware or antivirus software won't remove them.
   - Also check for suspicious services, you can also disable them from `msconfig`. Hint: check the *Hide Microsoft services* option to make sure you don't disable something important.
   - Disable or remove any extensions of your browser.
2. Reset your `hosts` file (✓).
3. Try accesing the same site from another computer, if the problem isn't present, it's most certainly a problem with your computer, repeat steps `1` and `2`, or in the worst case do a clean reinstall.
4. If the problem persists, it's most certainly an issue with your DNS (your router):

   - Change the default DNS of your router, I recommend using [Google's Public DNS addresses](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/): `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`. They're fast and relatively more secure than your ISP's.
   - Change the DNS that your router provides to DHCP clients (you'll have to renew your connection after this).
   - Change the DNS addresses that your network adapter uses.
   - If all of the above fails, try resetting your router to the default factory settings, and change your DNS addresses again.

Comment: The problem is present on other devices, which means it could be the router. If it is the router, the best approach is to completely reset it to factory defaults (unless you know what to look for) and then put a strong password on it.

Comment: That won't help if the problem is on his ISP's DNS server, whose address is part of the default factory settings.

Comment: If it's his ISPs DNS server there would be hundreds of people complaining, and it would be fixed. Also, that would not be part of the factory default settings, it would be assigned via DHCP

Comment: The address that is sent via the DHCP **is** on the factory settings on some routers, but anyway he should be able to change it. Also, he didn't mention about any other people complaining or not.

Comment: Broken ankle prevented me from looking at this the last few days :( will try your advice now.

Comment: No problem, champion. Get better soon, by the way.

Comment: I updated in my original post. I really appreciate the help on this.